# Unit testing Vim script-local functions with Vimrunner

Tags: unit-testing, vim, vimrunner

I'm using [Vimrunner](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/vimrunner) to unit-test a Vim plugin.  Everything is working, but I'm looking for a better/canonical way to execute script-local functions.  Since they're not directly visible outside the script, I'm currently exposing the script's `<SID>` and prepending that to my calls in order to run them.

I have to add this code to my plugin to expose the SID:

```
function! s:SID()
  let fullname = expand("<sfile>")
  return matchstr(fullname, '<SNR>\d\+_')
endfunction
let g:my_plugin_SID = s:SID()
```

That will expose the SID as e.g. `<SNR>18_`.  Since Vim functions are all global, and just name-munged, script-local functions can be invoked outside the script by prefixing the SID:

```
:call <SNR>18_some_function()
```

Then I do this in a spec:

```
describe "s:reverse_string" do
  let!(:sid) { VIM.command("echo g:my_plugin_SID") }

  def reverse_string(string)
    VIM.command("echo #{sid}reverse_string('#{string}')")
  end

  it "does something" do
    reverse_string("foo").should == "oof"
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply expose script-local functions: Turn `s:MyFunc` into `MyPlugin#MyFunc`. After all, function visibility is only by convention, anyway; nothing (except the cumbersome name lookup) prevents script-local functions from being called, anyway.

Sometimes, I deviate from that and do want to invoke script-local functions from tests. My approach is quite similar to yours, but instead of exposing the `<SID>` from within the plugin, I've written helper functions to parse the `<SID>` from the `:scriptnames` output. It's slower (I don't care; my tests are integration tests), but I don't have to pollute the plugin itself with test code. Here's an example showing the `Sid()` and `SidInvoke()` helpers:

```
let s:SID = Sid('autoload/EditSimilar/Substitute.vim')
function! s:Is( input, expected, description )
    let l:got = SidInvoke(s:SID, printf("IsWildcardPathPattern('%s')", a:input))
    call vimtap#Is(l:got, a:expected, a:description)
endfunction
```

Comment: I was headed in that direction, but I'm hesitant to up-scope things for testing.  I know it doesn't really matter, but I like to keep the namespaces as meaningful as Vim allows.  I like the idea of parsing it out of `:scriptnames` to avoid injecting test code into production.  Still open to other suggestions.

Comment: I have been trying to replace my s:MyFunction() with MyPlugin#MyFunction(), but then a call to it in a mapping in the same file seems not to be working. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Sathors: `MyPlugin` must be the exact name of your plugin, of course.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, can you share the implementation of Sid() and SidInvoke(), please?

Answer (score 2):

Use this to get the script number:

```
let sid = matchlist(execute('scriptnames'), '\([0-9]\+\): [^ ]*autoload/my_vimscript.vim')[1]
```

and this to invoke a script-local function (`s:Test()` in this example)

```
execute("call <snr>" . sid . "_Test()")
```

Comment: Will this return the value from *_Test() function? I'm using Vader and I want to test the return value of an local function